# Exporting a list of subscribers out of mysql

Tags: mysql

I am very new to mySQL and I want to export a list of subscribers to a CSV file. The subscribers are found in wp_post_notif_subscriber.

From here I am lost. So any help would be nice.

Comment: Consider taking a short tutorial at http://www.mysqltutorial.org/
That might clarify how querying a database works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to get a list of all records in the table "wp_post_notif_subscriber" from a mySQL database which you have access to.

To get all the rows from some table, query the mySQL database with: 
`SELECT * FROM <table_name>`
To get only some columns use:
`SELECT <column_name1, column_name2, ...> FROM <table_name>`

**In your case, seems like you need:**
`SELECT * FROM wp_post_notif_subscriber`

That should return you an array with the data you need. How you export to a CSV file depends on the rest of your development environment.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks i somehow did not find the table name but did now so this worked!